# HttpClient obtained from WebApplicationFactory handles request headers with multiple values differently?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

I'm playing around with WebApplicationFactory to use it in the integration tests of our API, but it seems like the HttpClient that I obtain from WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient() handles the headers of an HttpRequestMessage differently, compared to an HttpClient that is instantiated directly using "new HttpClient()"?

As an example, I've got an API with a "HeadersController" and a single HttpGet that just returns the number of "custom-header" values:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class HeadersController : ControllerBase
    {
        public HeadersController(ILogger<HeadersController> logger)
        { }

        [HttpGet]
        public int Get()
        {
            return HttpContext.Request.Headers["custom-header"].Count();
        }
    }
```

In a second console app, two HttpClients are created, one using WebApplicationFactory, a second directly using 'new HttpClient()'. The Fetch method creates a request, adds a custom header with multiple values and sends it. Yet, using client1, the api returns "2" while with client2 i get "1". Whether "1" or "2" is correct, I was at least expecting both to return the same value. What am I missing here?

```
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Api.Program>();
            var client1 = factory.CreateClient();
            var x = await Fetch(client1);
            Console.WriteLine($"Using WebApplicationFactory: {x}");


            var client2 = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7143") };
            var y = await Fetch(client2);
            Console.WriteLine($"Using HttpClient: {y}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async Task<int> Fetch(HttpClient client)
        {
            var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "headers");
            msg.Headers.Add("custom-header", new string[] { "value1", "value2" });
            var response = await client.SendAsync(msg);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return int.Parse(content);
        }
```

[screenshot of console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOtWV.png)

src: https://github.com/rainonwednesday/HeaderTest

Comment: Using different libraries the default header may be different.  You have one library that works.  All you need to do is to fix the header on non working solution to match the working solution.  The same request (not matter what library) should return the same results.  Check the UserAgent Header and make sure the head is the same in working and non working app.

Comment: well, what are the headers? most likely `WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient()` is the way to go.